# retorna error 422 value is not a valid dict

Tags: javascript, python, fetch, fastapi

estoy tratando de conusmir una api con fecth y me retorna este error en el body aun cuando le envio un dato json

`{"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"value is not a valid dict","type":"type_error.dict"}]}`

Route del endpoint de la api:

```
def create_customer(self, customer:Customer):
    
    try:
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO fintech.customers (first_name, last_name, email,         cellphone, identification_type, identification_number, comment, company_id, created_at,      updated_at, is_active) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",      (customer.first_name, customer.last_name, customer.email, customer.cellphone,      customer.identification_type, customer.identification_number, customer.comment,     customer.company_id, datetime.datetime.now(),datetime.datetime.now(), 'true'))
        self.connection.commit()
        return JSONResponse(status_code = 201, content = {"mesagge":"El cliente se registro con exito"})
    except:
        return JSONResponse(status_code = 500, content = {"mesagge":"Error al registrar el cliente"})
```

Schema del endpoint de la api:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Customer(BaseModel):
first_name: str
last_name: str
email: str
cellphone: str
identification_type: str
identification_number: str
comment: str
company_id: int
```

route del endpoint

```
@customer_router.post('/customer/create', tags=['customer'], status_code=200)
def post_customer(customer:Customer):
db = CustomerService(connection).create_customer(customer)
return print(jsonable_encoder(db))
```

Request:

```
data = {
        'first_name': first_name,
        'last_name': last_name,
        'email': email,
        'cellphone': cellphone,
        'identification_type': identification_type,
        'identification_number': identification_number,
        'comment': comment,
        'company_id': parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('company_id'))
    }

    console.log(data)
    fetch(endpoint + '/create',{
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
```

No logro entender el error ya que le paso el json en el body de la peticion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lo que tengan este error la solución que me funciono fue agregar en el fetch el header

```
headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
           }
```

y en el main de la api

```
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins = ["*"],
    allow_methods = ["*"]
)
```